# About Linux file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-disk-free

Just set a Fedora 22 system on VMWare with 60GB. When inputting the "df" command, the system displayed this:

```
Filesystem              1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  38440424 4140700  32324020  12% /
devtmpfs                  2009804       0   2009804   0% /dev
tmpfs                     2017796      92   2017704   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     2017796     872   2016924   1% /run
tmpfs                     2017796       0   2017796   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                     2017796     532   2017264   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                  487652   79147    378809  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  18701036   49464  17678568   1% /home
```

What is the exact size of each 1K-blocks? Does the  /dev/mapper/fedora-root contain the /dev/mapper/fedora-home?
I'm so confused with "df" command.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from the `df` output that `/dev/mapper/fedora-home` can currently be reached at `/home` which is its *mount point*. Because the mount point for `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` is at `/` farther up the directory tree, anything that `/dev/mapper/fedora-root` has in `/home` is not accessible by normal means until and unless `/dev/mapper/fedora-home` gets unmounted.

As David Schwartz noted, a 1K-block is a unit of one (binary) kilobyte, which is 1024 bytes. Because no one has bothered to change it since the time when it was important to performance, `df` still reports sizes in terms of the device's block size. That value does vary. There are still plenty of devices around that have a block size of 512 bytes. For output consistently in kilobytes, you can use `df -k`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the exact size of each 1K-blocks?

1,024 bytes.

> Does the /dev/mapper/fedora-root contains the /dev/mapper/fedora-home?

They're separate filesystems, that's why they appear on separate lines in the `df` output.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot. Others like devtmpfs, tmpfs and other systems are also separated?